# Intentionally make duplicate rows in sqlite select query

Tags: sqlite

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM t1;
```

I would like to modify the statement so I receive a response that looks something like:

```
a, b
a, b
.
.
.
a, b
```

where I get the same response (a, b) the same number of times as the value of c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires a [recursive common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursivecte):

```
WITH RECURSIVE repeated(a, b, count) AS (
  SELECT a, b, c FROM t1 WHERE c > 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a, b, count - 1 FROM repeated WHERE count > 1
)
SELECT a, b FROM repeated;
```